# Enable https on GitLab CE with Letsencrypt with Apache2 running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, gitlab, lets-encrypt

As in the title:

How can I enable https on GitLab CE (9.1.4) with lets-encrypt and Apache2 running on Ubuntu 14.04?

Some Background:
HTTPS works for my domain. E.g. www.example.com is establishing a secure connection via https. Safari says

> Issued by: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>
> Expires: Tuesday, 8. August 2017 at 16:12:00 Central European Summer Time

I'm configured Gitlab CE as followed first with http in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:1337'
```

This works fine, but my goal is to use the power of lets-encrypt to secure my connection to my gitlab instance.

I followed many tutorials changing my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as folling:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com:1337'

nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/example.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/example.com.key"
```

Also I added just for testing if it works to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_https'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 1337
```

But nothing worked! What I'm doing wrong?

Additional info:
I copied from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem` to `/etc/gitlab/ssl/example.com.crt`
and
I copied from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem` to `/etc/gitlab/ssl/example.com.key`

I'm using apache2 as my "front" server, and the nginx instance is the built-in nginx shipped with GitLabe CE

Comment: You mention Apache, but the configuration you show relates to Nginx. Are you using both the build-in Nginx server from GitLab and putting Apache in front of that?

Also, certificates should be copied to `/etc/gitlab/ssl`, not `/gitlab/ssl` unless you're using Docker and `/gitlab` is the local directory that is mounted at `/etc/gitlab` in the container.

Comment: Hi Drew, the path was a typo-error of mine. I fixed that in my question - sorry for that. Yes I'm using both the build-in Nginx server from GitLab and putting Apache in front of that. I'm not using Docker.